# How to make UnityEngine.Event.numeric be true?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a simple tool that needs to check if a numeric key has been pressed using `OnGUI` in a `MonoBehaviour`. I tried every keys of my keyboard (even num pad and classical numerci keys) and none of them seems to set the property `Event.numeric` to true.

I am wondering what key will trigger the value change of that property.

Here is my sample code (**Unity 2020.3.20 LTS**)

```cs
private void OnGUI()
{
    var evt = Event.current;
    if (evt.type != EventType.KeyDown) return;
    if (!evt.numeric) return;

    Debug.Log("Foo");
}
```

Comment: Was your keypad activated? Afaik it is supposed to be keys from the numpad but it has to be active of course ;)

Comment: @derHugo affirmative, it was active

Comment: Hm strange .. I can't tell you more then the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-numeric.html) .. maybe your keyboard is weird? :'D

Comment: @derHugo I asked a friend to do the same sample test and same result, no response...